# Why am I seeing weird behavior with LED bulbs in old light fixtures?

Tags: led, series, halogen

I have two light fixtures on my front porch. I believe they're from the late 60s, when the house was built.

I believe they're wired in series since removing one bulb causes the other to stop working. They work just fine when two 60w halogen bulbs are in the fixtures.

I bought LED bulbs. If replace both halogen bulbs with the LED bulbs, they do not light up. If I put in one LED bulb and one halogen bulb, the halogen bulb does not work, but the LED bulb works. Swapping the two bulbs yields the same result; the halogen bulb never lights up and the LED bulb lights up.

I'd be very grateful if someone could explain what on earth is going on.

Comment: "I believe they're wired in series since removing one bulb causes the other to stop working."  ...well, There's your problem!

Comment: Are LED bulbs not usable in fixtures wired in series like that?

Comment: No residential lights should be wired like that.  Call an electrician.

Answer (score 2):

They may have been wired like that to get roughly the same light as a single bulb (two 60 W bulbs each running at 30 W) while making them last a lot longer in a spot where it might not be so easy to change them. Each bulb is basically running at half voltage.

LED bulbs need the full voltage, so putting two in series isn't going to work.

When you put in one of each type the halogen bulb's cold resistance will be a low enough to let the LED get enough voltage to light, but the LED runs at a much lower current so there's not enough current to let the halogen bulb light up all the way, it just sits there acting like a warm resistor.

Incandescent bulbs, including halogens, have a non-linear resistance, their resistance when cold is low and gets higher as they heat up, so it take more current to get them started than it takes to keep them lit.

Comment: "They may have been wired like that to get roughly the same light as a single bulb (two 60 W bulbs each running at 30 W)".  Not only is this a **Bad Idea**, but it is against code, and you run the risk of **being killed until you are dead**.  Do not do this.  Do not perpetuate the idea that this is even an option.  If your lighting circuit is currently like this, then your insurance company will want to talk to you.  You need to get it fixed by an electrician. (North America)

Answer (score 1):

LEDs brightness is (generally) proportional to the current through them but since they are **diodes** and not resistors the current varies non-linearly with voltage. In effect they need a certain minimum voltage to turn on.

[image]

*Figure 1. One way of making a mains-powered LED lamp.*

If you open an LED bulb you will find a series-connected string of LEDs and the forward voltage of the number of LEDs in the string will add up to close to the mains supply voltage. With two lamps in series you'll only have half the design voltage on each LED so they won't light.

The halogen lamp has a relatively low resistance so with that in circuit the LED lamp will see almost full mains voltage.

I've written a bit more on mains LED lamps in the context of dimmers [here](http://lednique.com/bulbs/dimmers-for-leds/).

In anycase, the house wiring is incorrect and should be corrected.